# Protect DLL from external usage

Tags: c#, dll

I'll jump straight to the question. I have the following scenario:

1. Project A -> produces .dll A
2. Project B -> references .dll A and produces .dll B

The thing is, I create .dll B to re-write some of the classes from .dll A to have reduced functionality in order to be used by 3rd parties. But when Project B compiles, the entire .dll  A will be there.

So, is there any way in which I can "lock" / "hide" .dll A ?

Comment: Looks like you need ILMerge.http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: ILMerge just create one dll from more, doesn't it? It doesn't prevent from accessing it's functionality.

Comment: @JanBarta:Yes Combine dllA+dllB as a single DLL.and guess dllA and dllB would be hidden

Comment: Questions about "code hiding", "obfuscation" and "intellectual property protection" are asked quite frequently, where the consensus is: no, you can't, any binary can be decompiled. If you really don't want to expose your code, host it yourself and expose it through a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Should't you use different approach? Create dll with smaller subset of functionality and then expand it with others dlls? Problem is that once you created you dll it can be accessed, for example with reflection, even if you use "internal".

Comment: I cannot change the entire implementation of Project A just for this small part :)

Comment: Maybe look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). You could specify in dll A to be called only from dll B. If you sign it, I think it could help.